# Any way to synchronise a "Sent" folder between a desktop emailer and an online service?

Tags: email, email-client

I have gradually abandonned my offline emailer and switched to an online one, but I still use it to regularly collect my received emails and archive them. Is there something that would also allow me to collect the mails originaly sent online (other than systematically cc'ing them to myself), or (even better) to 'synchronise' the **sent** folders of the 2 emailers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your online provider supports IMAP, that would be the way to go.